# Autocomplete textfield in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I am working in `Xcode 6.4`(Objective C). I have an array of names.I want to autocomplete my `textfield` while user enter something.If user enters "a" in `TextField`, a dropdown with all names which start from "a"  must be shown.Like that if user enters "ab" in `TextField`, a dropdown with all names which start from "ab"  must be shown.

I know a `TableView` is needed for dropdown.I tried some examples by searching SO and other sites(RayWendelich.com). But i couldn't solve this issue.Please help me with a simple solution.(I am new to the iOS development).

Comment: what is the issue? what you tried?

Comment: Do you need dropdown like or the searching functionality?

Comment: I need Searching Functionality

Comment: show the solution you have that got closest and tell us what it does wrong

Comment: I have used the following code.

Comment: - (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {
   
    [_autocompleteurls removeAllObjects];
    
    for(NSString *curString in _pasturls) {
        NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
        if (substringRange.location == 0) {
            [_autocompleteurls addObject:curString];
        }
        
        [_tableview reloadData];
    }
}

Comment: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    _tableview.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"sajith");
    NSLog(@"urls3=%@",_autocompleteurls);
    
    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
    return YES;
}

Comment: Hi, sujith K, Please have a look  https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField

Comment: ok.I tried MLPAutoCompleteTextField.I don't know how to integrate it with other project.(I am new to iOS development)

Comment: refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113380/autocomplete-for-uitextfield-in-ios) for your problem, i think that is all you want.

Answer (score 2):

For that you can use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method of `UITextField`.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *searchText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    for(NSString *strName in arrNames) {
        if([strName hasPrefix:searchText]) {
            // Entered text match with names array
            // Store it in temporary array.
        }
    }

   return YES;
}
```

Comment: what's the problem? Which objects are stored in array and which text are you searching?

Answer (score 0):

-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

```
     NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];

     substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    [self searchFoodNameFromString:substring];
```

return YES;

}

-(void)searchFoodNameFromString:(NSString *)strFood {

```
if(strFood.length>2)
{
     [arrAutoSuggFood removeAllObjects];
    NSInteger counter = 0;
    for(NSString *name in itemArray)
    {
        NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:strFood options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(r.length>2)
        {
            [arrAutoSuggFood addObject:name];
        }

        counter++;

    }

    if (arrAutoSuggFood.count > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",arrAutoSuggFood);
        self.viewAutoSuggest.hidden = FALSE;
        [self displayAutoSuggestView];

    }
    else
    {
        self.viewAutoSuggest.hidden = TRUE;
    }

}
else
{
    [self.viewAutoSuggest setHidden:TRUE];

}
```

}

-(void)displayAutoSuggestView {

```
CGFloat autoSuggViewHeight;
if ([arrAutoSuggFood count] == 1) {
    autoSuggViewHeight = 44.0 * 1;
} else if ([arrAutoSuggFood count] == 2) {
    autoSuggViewHeight = 44.0 * 2;
} else {
    autoSuggViewHeight = 44.0 * 3;
}


[_viewAutoSuggest removeFromSuperview];
_viewAutoSuggest.frame = CGRectMake(addFoodAnotationTxt.frame.origin.x+8, addFoodAnotationTxt.frame.origin.y - autoSuggViewHeight, addFoodAnotationTxt.frame.size.width, autoSuggViewHeight);
[_scrlVwMain bringSubviewToFront:_viewAutoSuggest];
[_scrlVwMain addSubview:_viewAutoSuggest];

_tblAutoSugg.frame = self.viewAutoSuggest.bounds;
_tblAutoSugg.delegate = self;
_tblAutoSugg.dataSource = self;
[_viewAutoSuggest addSubview:_tblAutoSugg];
 [_tblAutoSugg reloadData];
```

}