# How to filter Google Places API autocomplete data to obtain Countries and States

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-api

I am having trouble filtering the Google Places API data to get countries and states.

The requirement is to follows:

In my application I have to use 2 textfields and when user type in the 1st text field I have to get google places api to show only counties in a table view.

Once the user select the country for example Australia then select the second textfield and type, I have to get the google place api to only show the states of the selected country in another table view.

I have tried to do as requested but was not able to do that. Is this possible to do using google place api or not? Or else what kind of thing should I have to do to achieve the requirement ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: when you get the country name, fetch all the states names (using google) and store it. Then using the auto complete, display the according state name.(this is just an idea. i don't know weather it will works or not). Refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Comment: this will help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26113380/autocomplete-for-uitextfield-in-ios  In this change the array with your city names.

Comment: Yes, keeping the all countries list and their states in the application will definitely work but I am trying to find out whether is it possible to do using the Google Autocomplete API?

Comment: http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json this will get the all countries. Refer this api for autocomplete country names. https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

```
In my application I have to use 2 textfields and when user type in the 1st text field list of country data show
and 2nd textfields that is call CityName
I suggest use this code
First You need to 

var resultsViewController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController?

resultsViewController = GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController()

resultsViewController?.delegate = self

then after you need to use UISearchbar

searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsViewController)
searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = resultsViewController

 if !regionCode.isEmpty{
                let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
                filter.type = .city
                filter.country = regionCode
                resultsViewController?.autocompleteFilter = filter
    }

After you use GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController delegate Method


 func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                               didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    place.formattedAddress 
    }
```